# sum by number rows range in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column containing many price rows I want to determine the sum of 25 rows range then the next 25 rows range etc. I've done this, it's ok only for the first list:

```
select sum(substr(UNICOLON,-14,10)) over (order by to_number(:P22_UNI) rows between current row and 24 following) as R
from CNAM_CONCAT;
```

Comment: Can you please post the sample data and expected result?

Comment: Let say I have 140 row items containing prices that will be printed as reports every page contains 25 rows, and I want to indicate on each page the sum of the 25 rows price located in this page (page 1 will have the sum of the 25 rows on it the page 2 will have the sum of the 25 rows on it etc). I will have finally 6 pages in total for 140 items.

Comment: Please post how your data looks in the table and how you want it on the report.

Answer (score 0):

[Report is the sum of the 25 rows in the page 1/2 and TOTAL A PAYER is the sum of all rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7okyN.png)

Comment: the first page is ok it gives the good result but the second one gives the same amount, and I want it to do the same procedure as the first page, I mean sums what is in it. I have 31 rows in my example but in reality it will be more than 200 rows.